# LWC: Share @wire between two components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

What would be the best way to share `@wire` between two lightning web components?

I went through [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_javascript_share_code) article but I figured that `@wire` is not going to work outside of a LWC. At least I couldn't trigger the method.

In this case would it make sense to make a new "helper" LWC just so that it can perform the wire work. Then load that "helper" LWC in my other 2 components and pass the data from `@wire` to them?

Comment: You can "extend" components. Have you tried that?

Comment: @sfdcfox I cannot find a link to this. If it's not too much to ask can you give me a link so I can read the documentation. From the sound of it it should be what I am looking for!

Comment: or use a service components that then triggers an event that the other components listen for or use the pub sub model and have your other elements subscribe  to the event.  That way you have the service compnent that does the work and just notifies any components that listens for it's results

Comment: Okay I found this(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:component/documentation) and this(https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html). 

@GarethJordan - That was my initial idea as well. I was asking for opinions on what people consider the best approach. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pubsub` for sending data across components - whether wire service or any other event.

**Below is `listener` component:**

import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners } from 'c/pubsub';

```
export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @track myResponse;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    connectedCallback() {
        registerListener('wiredResponse', this.getWiredResponse, this);
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
        unregisterAllListeners(this);
    }
    getWiredResponse(response) {
        this.myResponse = response;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={myResponse}>
        <template if:true={myResponse.data}>
            <div> data - {myResponse.data} </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={myResponse.error}>
            <div>error - {myResponse.error}</div>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

1. You should download and save `pubsub` module from [HERE](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/pubsub)
2. Register listener on init (connectCallback) and implement the method to which the response has to be passed. Here its `getWiredResponse` in which the response from wire service is assigned to `myResponse`.
3. Also unregister in disconnected callback.

---

**Firing component:**

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import check from '@salesforce/apex/poc.check';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { fireEvent } from 'c/pubsub';

export default class PocTable extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    @track checkResp;

    @wire(check)
    getcheckResp(result) {
        this.checkResp = result;
        console.log('poc table wire => ', JSON.stringify(this.checkResp));
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'wiredResponse', this.checkResp);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={checkResp.data}>
        <div> checkResp data - {checkResp.data} </div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={checkResp.error}>
        <div> checkResp error - {checkResp.error}</div>
    </template>
</template>
```

1. In this you will need `fireEvent` import and you can fire the event whenever necessary. In this case inside wire service.

In both listener and firing component should have `CurrentPageReference`.

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
```

---

**IMPORTANT:**

1. When Wire service is implemented on any standard methods like `getRecord`, it uses Lighning data service, so you dont need any custom functionality to optimise code here.
2. When wire service is used to invoke apex methods, we should be using `Cacheable=true` on methods mandatorily. So, even if you use wire service on same method in multiple components, the apex method will return the response only once and the wire service will share the same data resource from client cache. So, it is not really logical/needed to handle the optimisation. If 1 wire output is the input for another wire service in another component, then it makes more sense to implement the same wire service in target component. `pubsub` is application event and so it should not really be used in this case.
3. Component extension will not work on wire service. This is because wire service is already optimised and LWC does not really need it that way.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very thorough answer. I have a question regarding the fireEvent. You are feeding it `this.checkResp`. Does `this.checkResp` have to be a primitive value as Salesforce were advising in their documentation, for `customEvent`, to only pass primitive values to avoid passing value by reference? As stated [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch).

Comment: If its Object or array it will be passed by reference. So, the same rules apply => better to pass the clone.

Comment: Are you saying that if I want to pass an Object through the event that it would be safe as long as I pas its clone instead?

Comment: The only problem in any event if you dont clone it, the modification in target component will change the object in source component also. So, if you are sure it will never be modified and only be used for reading data, then its not a problem.